# Natural numbers in triangle groups

Tags: group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

I'm just getting starting looking into triangle groups for an undergraduate project and had a question about triangle groups generated by reflections in the triangle sides.

The triangles take angles $\pi/a, \pi/b, \pi/c$, in the Euclidean case $\pi/a + \pi/b + \pi/c = \pi$. My reference source says $ a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}$ - why is this so? Could we not also have groups where $a,b,c$ are not all natural numbers?

Edit: The triangle group is a reflection group with presentation
$\Delta(a,b,c) = \langle p,q,r \mid p^{2} =  q^{2} = r^{2} = (pq)^{c} = (qr)^{a} = (rp)^{b} =  1 \rangle$.

Comment: You haven't actually specified any groups in your post, you've just written some equation. So I have no idea what you might mean by a "group where $a$, $b$, $c$ are not all natural numbers". Your post would be greatly improved by writing out exactly what kinds of groups you are referring to.

Comment: You would not get the tiling.  The product of reflections in two adjacent sides is a rotation by twice the angle between them, so if this angle is $\frac\pi a$ with integer $a$ and you do this $a$ times and you have a full $2\pi$ rotation getting back to where you started, i.e. the identity.  If $a$ is a non-integer rational then you have to go round more than once; while if $a$ is irrational then you never get there

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you, say, work in the Euclidean plane, there will be triangles with arbitrary angles $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, as long as they satisfy $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\pi$. Hence, in order to construct such a triangle $T$ you do not need the assumption $a, b, c\in {\mathbb N}$. However, on the next step, you will be taking a group of Euclidean isometries generated by reflections $p, q, r$ in the sides of $T$. What would it even mean for this group to have a  presentation with $(pq)^c=1$, etc, if $c$ is not a natural number? For the subgroup to have the presentation that you wrote, one needs $a, b, c$ to be natural numbers. Once you understand the proof, you will see where this condition is used.